# Export entire Mosaic with "Equal-Arc" spatial reference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, mosaic-dataset

I have several mosaic datasets contain a total of about 1000 images, each about 500mb in size. Unfortunately our customer needs a file format different than the one we are using and needs the imagery all with the equal-arc spatial referencing.

Is there a way to export the imagery from the mosaic dataset so that the spatial referencing for each image is the same as the equal arc zone that corresponds to its location?

So far all I could think of was just choosing the Data frame as the spatial reference source when exporting the imagery as a different file type, but in that case I have to choose one of the arc zones for the data frame, meaning most of the data will be wrong (The mosaics cover entire countries).

Has anybody found any elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Have a look at your environment Output Coordinate System and Cell Size, set these implicitly and use Copy Raster to convert your whole mosaic to a format that is required.. Do you still want tiles but in the new spatial reference? It is possible to create a mosaic dataset with one coordinate system and have rasters in a different one - I don't recommend it for ongoing use but you could use it to export to a mosaic.

Comment: The goal is to have each image converted into the appropriate file type and coordinate system, and to keep them as their own individual images. The images will be given to the customer as individual images, not a mosaic.

Comment: The way I do it. Create approximately same size fishnet in destination projection. Project 1 tile to source prj. Use it to clip from mosaic. Project clipped raster. Use tile to clip. Next tile. Multiprocessing helps to do it much faste

Comment: The problem is that I need to use different projections for each image, or at least for groups of them. Because equal arc is much like the UTM zones, in the sense that a image in a different location would require a different spatial reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1000 images for which you have built a mosaic dataset and they are in some coordinate system, or even a mixture of coordinate systems? Your client wants all the source rasters supplied in an equal-arc coordinate system?

In ArcGIS 10.4 there is a tool [Export Mosaic Dataset Items](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/export-mosaic-dataset-items.htm) which honours the environment setting output coordinate system. Run this will convert the rasters referenced in your mosaic into new rasters with what ever coordinate system you set in the environment setting.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that all of the imagery is not in the same equal arc region. Does ArcGIS automatically compensate for that? Using that tool you can only use the coordinate system of the data frame or the original data source, in the data frame you have to choose only one equal arc region.

Comment: I would imagine ArcGIS would not compensate for different regions, I think most tools expect data to be in one area. The tool I point you too is able to subset data using SQL. Why not add a field to the mosaic datasets, code up you data into regions 1..2..3...X... then run the tool for as many regions sub-setting the data and apply the appropriate regional equal-arc coordinate system?